# Pass params of one view to a controller

Tags: java, forms, playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm using the Play Framework 2.x and I'm trying to pass the value of one button to a method in my controller, I have this:

View:

```
<form action="@routes.Application.changeLanguage()" method="get"/>
    <input name="language" type="submit" value="en" title="@Messages("button.en")" </>
    <input name="language" type="submit" value="es" title="@Messages("button.es")" </>
</form>
```

Route:

```
GET     /       controllers.Application.changeLanguage(language: String ?= "")
```

Controller:

```
public static Result changeLanguage(String language){
    if(language == null || language.isEmpty()){
        changeLang("en");

    } else {
        changeLang(language);

    }

    return ok(index.render(""));
}
```

In my URL I can see this language=en but the method changeLanguage never receive the value of language, some one can I help me??

Comment: I've just recreated this test case and it works pretty fine. Are you sure you don't have any other action mapped with GET    /  ? Make sure that the changeLanguage action is called.

Answer (score 0):

just edit routes like this;

GET     /changeLanguage       controllers.Application.changeLanguage(language: String ?= "")

ps: check that changeLanguage is unique in your routes file.